# Silverstripe - Turn modules on or off in config

Tags: yaml, silverstripe

Is it possible to activate or deactivate modules based on entries in either config.yml or _config.php?

Say I've built an Image Gallery module but don't want it showing on the site yet, can it be deactivated in the config files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SilverStripe scans all directories in webroot for modules. If you place a file called `manifest_exclude` in any directory, it won't be scanned and not included; the autoloader won't find it and you cannot call your class without including the file manually.

Answer (score 4):

Only if the module has provided functionality to do so.

You can add your own `private static $enable_module = true`

```
class MyClass extends Object
{
    private static $enable_module = true;

    public function doMyThing()
    {
        if (!Config::inst()->forClass('MyClass')->enable_module) {
            return false;
        }

        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

then you can disable it via YML

```
MyClass:
  enable_module: false
```

would disable it.

For templates you could add

```
public function getGalleryEnabled() {
    return Config::inst()->forClass('MyClass')->enable_module;
}
```

to your `Page_Controller` class and then

```
<% if $GalleryEnabled %><% include MyGallery %><% end_if %>
```

The best practice is: *never develop on the live site*